# Http Status for partial response in the case where API makes calls to multiple APIs

Tags: rest, api, http, http-headers

I have an API whose job is to aggregate resources obtained by calling multiple other APIs and then give out the aggregated response to the client. Currently even if one or more dependent API calls fail, I go ahead and aggregate response from the other dependent APIs and then give them out to the client with a 2xx status. In case all of the dependent API calls fail, I still give out a 2xx with empty list.

In case one or more dependent API calls fail, I want to give out an indication to the client. I was thinking of using the HTTP code [206](https://httpstatuses.com/206). What would be the best approach to handle this scenario. Is giving out a 206 with the names of the dependent services that failed to give out a 2xx as part of a header the correct approach. If yes, what should this header be called?

Answer (score 2):

> I was thinking of using the HTTP code 206.

I can't promise, but that seems like a very bad idea; see RFC 7233

> The 206 (Partial Content) status code indicates that the server is successfully fulfilling a range request

If the client didn't send you a range request (see RFC 7233 for the specifics), then I don't think there is any benefit in answering as if it had.  General-purpose components are likely to get confused.

As for what status code to use instead: the response code, like the headers, is meta data so that general purpose components can understand what is going on and provide intelligent assistance.  The *details* of what you are doing, that are to be understood by the bespoke client, belong in the response body.

(Analogy - on the web, the status code and the headers are for the (general purpose) browser.  The response body is for the human being.)

[200 OK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) is probably what you want to be using here; with a "representation of the status of the action" in the payload.